# Can I change ContentType header for a particular request after declaring ContentType = Application.Json in DefaultRequest of my KtorClient

Tags: android, content-type, ktor

I'm working on my android project and I'm making a request function for uploading file that makes request as given below,

```
httpClient.put(uri) {
    body = MultiPartFormDataContent(formData {
        append("file", fileContent, Headers.build {
            append(HttpHeaders.ContentType, fileMimeType)
            append(HttpHeaders.ContentDisposition, ContentDisposition.File.withParameter(ContentDisposition.Parameters.FileName, fileOriginalName))
        })
    })
}
```

So as you can see this request has a ContentType header, but I already declared ContentType header in my Ktor HttpClient,

```
install(DefaultRequest) {
                url {
                    protocol = URLProtocol.HTTP
                    host = baseURL
                }

                headers {
                    append(HttpHeaders.ContentType, ContentType.Application.Json)
                    append(HttpHeaders.Authorization, accessToken)
                    append(USER, user)
                }
            }
```

So my question is which ContentType is my request going to take? if it can't take the ContentType that I specified in my request function then how can I make it accept ContentType different than default one?

Comment: Hi @EGOR-IND did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you try to set the `Content-Type` header in the `DefaultRequest` feature then you will get `io.ktor.http.UnsafeHeaderException: Header(s) [Content-Type] are controlled by the engine and cannot be set explicitly`.

So if you remove the line `append(HttpHeaders.ContentType,ContentType.Application.Json)` then the `Content-Type` of a request will be `multipart/form-data` and the `Content-Type` for the `file` body part ‒ value of `fileMimeType` variable.

Comment: Thanks aleksei, so if I remove the append that you mentioned, then the ContentType of the request will become multipart/form-data. So what if I also want to post json data and make ContentType = Application.Json in my other requests. I'm using data class with kotlinx.serialization and assigning that data class to body to send data in json format.

Comment: Same is my concern because the network layer is common and it needs to know for which API i want what value of CONTENT-TYPE

Comment: @EGOR-IND figured this out with experiments and some SOF comments

Answer (score 0):

So I was fiddling around the same issue found out from some examples that

1. If you are using Multipart, you need to add `Content` in body
2. Header shouldnot be added at all in the request, as this will now automatically be handled by Ktor engine. Since, you already added header in the body.

Here is an example

```
return helper.getAuthClient(isMultiPartRequest = true).put {
        url {
            takeFrom(ApiConstants.BASE_URL)
            encodedPath = ApiConstants.UPLOAD_DOCUMENT
            body = MultiPartFormDataContent (
                formData {
                    append(
                        key = "file",
                        value =  request.file,
                        headers = io.ktor.http.Headers.build {
                            append(HttpHeaders.ContentDisposition, "filename=${request.fileName}")
                        }
                    )
                    append("fileName", request.fileName)
                }
            )

        }
    }
```

Here is what I do for headers.

```
private fun addCommonHeaders(headers: HeadersBuilder, isMultiPartRequest: Boolean = false) {
        headers.append(Headers.API_KEY, ApiConstants.API_KEY)
        headers.append(Headers.CORR_ID, randomUUID())
        headers.append(Headers.API_VERSION, Headers.Values.VERSION_V3)
        headers.append(Headers.PLATFORM, getUserPlatform())

        if(!isMultiPartRequest) {
            headers.append(Headers.CONTENT_TYPE, Headers.Values.CONTENT_JSON)
        }// this is where I decide, for Multipart, don't add any Content-Type headers.
    }
```

points to note:

1. `key` = the request key where you will send the `byteArray`
2. add more
   parameters, if your API contract demands, by further adding
   `append()` in succession

Note : `getAuthClient()` is simple custom function that provides the instance of `HttpClient` so ignore that.